# Nested for loop employing the current global Stata

Tags: for-loop, nested, global, stata

I am using a for loop:

```
foreach n of numlist 1/7 {
```

Then doing various things like...

```
recode ${controls`n'} (.=0)
pscore intervention_family ${controls`n'}, pscore(ps_oowb) 
blockid(bl_oowb)
```

where

```
$controls`n'
```

is a previously defined macro with a variables list in it.

E.g

```
global controls1 ///
age /// 
sex ///
```

This is all fine until I need to use another for loop as follows...

```
foreach var in $controls`n' {
  local i=`i'
    putexcel A`i'="`var'" B`i'="U" C`i'=`r(m1u_`var')' 
  D`i'=`r(m0u_`var')' 
  ......
}
```

I cannot put brackets round

```
$controls`n'
```

here as then Stata says 'code after brace on same line' but without them Stata does not seem to recognise this global.

Previously I was simply calling a macro

```
foreach var in $controls {
    ...
}
```

And it worked fine. 
Anyone know the correct syntax / work around?

Comment: In your last block of code tne local macro `i` is not defined that we can see.

Answer (score 0):

Try to "unpack" this structure via:

> ```
> foreach n of numlist 1/7 {
> foreach var of global controls`n' {
>
> }
> }
> ```

Comment: This is a good suggestion but I think the syntax is off. Should be "local contr ${controls`n'}", no?

Comment: Agreed, otherwise Stata evaluates `$controls` and `\`n'` and concatenates the results.

Comment: `foreach var of global controls\`n'` should work too. I don't see the need to pass its contents to a local: cut out the middle macro.